# Can more than one IP addresses be assigned to the same network interface?

Tags: ip-address, interface

Can more than one IP addresses be assigned  to the same network interface?

Is it correct that a network interface can be a physical one or a virtual one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can more than one IP addresses be assigned to the same network interface?

Absolutely. Some hosts even support using a statically configured IPv4 address plus a DHCP one. For IPv6 it's completely normal to have multiple IP addresses on each interface.

> Is it correct that a network interface can be a physical one or a virtual one?

A virtual interface behaves just like a physical one in that respect.